# Can we convert an NFA to a regular expression of polynomial length?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

Can we convert an NFA having $n$ states to a regular expression of length $\mathrm{poly}(n)$?

In contrast, it is well known that a regular expression of length $n$ can be easily converted to an $\mathcal{O}(n)$-state NFA.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is negative. See the survey article

[From Finite Automata to Regular Expressions and Back—A Summary on Descriptional Complexity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5594) by Hermann Gruber and Markus Holzer, *Int. J. Found. Comput. Sci.* **26**(8): 1009-1040 (2015),

which contains a thorough discussion of your question. Let me quote in particular Theorem 24:

> Let $n \geqslant 1$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be an $n$-state DFA or NFA over
>   alphabet $\Sigma$. Then size $|\Sigma| \cdot 2^{\theta(n)}$ is sufficient
>   and necessary in the worst case for a regular expression describing
>   $L(\mathcal{A})$. This already holds for alphabets with at least two
>   letters.